# A question on JavaScript .reduce method's accumulator

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce, accumulator

I was working on this problem to create a function using a reduce method that will get the max number in an array.

The instructor's answer is:

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 1, 3, 4];
const max = getMax(numbers);
console.log(max);
function getMax(array) {
   if (array.length === 0) return undefined;
   return array.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
       return (accumulator > current) ? accumulator : current
});
```

I tried something like this:

```
 return array.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
    if (accumulator < current)
        console.log(accumulator, current);
        return accumulator = current;
});
```

I added console.log (accumulator, current) because I wanted to see what's going on with my code. The log shows as follows:

[console.log of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjSJE.png)

> `1 2`
>   `2 3`
>   `3 4`
>   `4 5`
>   `1 3`
>   `3 4`
>   `4`

Question 1. I'd like to know why my function didn't give the right output (it returned 4, not the correct output 5). Shouldn't "accumulator" stay 5 when it is assigned as 5 during the loop?

Question 2. Why do I need to return (or add return in front of) array in the function, when there is already a return below the if statement?

Comment: Welcome to SO! `Math.max(...nums)` is surely easier. Your reduce version doesn't make much sense--the assignment in the return statement doesn't really achieve anything and accumulator and current are never changed--the `console.log` is conditionally logged. Avoid `console.log` until after the function ends--it's probably causing confusion.

Comment: You didn't use `{ ... }` after your `if` statement, so _only_ the first line `console.log(...)` is happening when the condition is met. The `accumlator = current` line always happens for each iteration. You must use `return` when using imperative style `if` _statement_. However you can skip `return` when using functional style _expressions_, ie `(accumulator, current) => accumulator < current ? current : accumulator` which says _"if accumulator is less than current, return current, else return accumulator"_.

Comment: whitch is the return value when `(accumulator >=current)` ? none, so the accumulator is empty

Comment: @ggorlen with the mention of "instructor" I would assume the point of the exercise is to write your own code to learn `reduce` or lambdas or something similar, and  `Math.max()` wouldn't be allowed.

Comment: Thank you all - could you answer my question #2, which you already might have, but I am still not sure if i understand. @Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't use `{ ... }` after your `if` statement, so *only* the first line `console.log(...)` is happening when the condition is met. The `accumlator = current` line always happens for each iteration. You must use `return` when using imperative style `if` *statement*. However you can skip `return` when using functional style *expressions*, ie `(accumulator, current) => accumulator < current ? current : accumulator` which says *"if accumulator is less than current, return current, else return accumulator"*.

Consider this decomposed program. When we see `max` as an independent function, it helps us see precisely the type of function `reduce` is expecting -

```js
const max = (a = 0, b = 0) =>
  a < b               // if a is less than b
    ? b               // return b
    : a               // otherwise return a
 
const getMax = (numbers = []) =>
  numbers.length === 0          // if numbers.length is zero
    ? undefined                 // return undefined
    : numbers.reduce(max)       // otherwise return reduction

console.log(getMax([1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 1, 3, 4]))
// 5

console.log(getMax([]))
// undefined

console.log(getMax())
// undefined
```

We can see `reduce` is produces the following computation -

```js
// given
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 1, 3, 4]

// starting with the first two
r = max(1, 2)

// then the next number
r = max(r, 3)

// then the next number
r = max(r, 4)

// then the next number
r = max(r, 4)
```

Or without intermediate `r = ...` -

```js
max(max(max(max(max(max(max(max(1, 2), 3), 4), 4), 5), 1), 3), 4)
```

We could write `getMax` without `reduce`, if we wanted -

```js
const max = (a = 0, b = 0) =>
  a < b
    ? b
    : a
 
const getMax = (numbers = []) =>
  numbers.length === 0 // without any numbers,
    ? undefined        // there can be no max.
: numbers.length === 1 // if we only have one,
    ? numbers[0]       // we already know max.
    : max(numbers[0], getMax(numbers.slice(1))) // else

console.log(getMax([1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 1, 3, 4]))
// 5

console.log(getMax([]))
// undefined

console.log(getMax())
// undefined
```

Or maybe you haven't learned `slice` yet. You can use an array index, `i`, to step thru your array -

```js
const max = (a = 0, b = 0) =>
  a < b
    ? b
    : a
 
const getMax = (numbers = [], i = 0) =>
  numbers.length === 0    // without any numbers,
    ? undefined           // there can be no max.
: i + 1 >= numbers.length // if the next i is not in bounds,
    ? numbers[i]          // this is the last number
    : max(numbers[i], getMax(numbers, i + 1)) // else

console.log(getMax([1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 1, 3, 4]))
// 5

console.log(getMax([]))
// undefined

console.log(getMax())
// undefined
```

Destructuring assignment can be used as well -

```js
const max = (a = 0, b = 0) =>
  a < b
    ? b
    : a
 
const getMax = ([ num, ...more ] = []) =>
  more.length === 0
    ? num
    : max(num, getMax(more))
    
console.log(getMax([1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 1, 3, 4]))
// 5

console.log(getMax([]))
// undefined

console.log(getMax())
// undefined
```

This might show you how you can invent your own `reduce` -

```js
const max = (a = 0, b = 0) =>
  a < b
    ? b
    : a
 
const reduce = (f, a = [], i = 0) =>
  a.length === 0    // without any numbers,
    ? undefined     // there can be no reduction.
: i + 1 >= a.length // if the next i is not in bounds,
    ? a[i]          // this is the last element
    : f(a[i], reduce(f, a, i + 1)) // else

const getMax = (numbers = []) =>
  reduce(max, numbers) // <-- our reduce!

console.log(getMax([1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 1, 3, 4]))
// 5

console.log(getMax([]))
// undefined

console.log(getMax())
// undefined
```

Comment: or simply `const getMax = (arr=[]) => arr.reduce((a,c)=>(a>c)?a:c,undefined)`

Comment: No, it is not so simple as that, Mister Mojo. `a = undefined` in the first iteration of the reducer, so you are doing `undefined > ...` which is an invalid comparison.

Comment: Would you agree that `const max1 = (a, b) => a > b ? a : b` is the same as `const max2 = (a, b) => a < b ? b : a`? Now can you explain why `numbers.reduce(max1, undefined)` returns `5` but `numbers.reduce(max2, undefined)` returns `undefined`. `max1` and `max2` are identical for all `x` and `y`. `max1` works not "perfectly", but by dumb luck. It just so happens that in JavaScript `undefined < x` returns `false` for all `x`, so `max1` stumbles upon the correct answer.

Comment: no, it's not the same. if `a===undefined`, `a > b ? a : b`  return `b`  and  `a < b ? b : a` return  `a` ; any comparison with undefined return false, that exactly why I made  `a > b` and  not  `a < b`. It's not a dumb luck.

Comment: When you give two equal functions an _undefined_ input you get an _undefined_ output... You make the mistake of passing `undefined` to `>` or `<` (or whatever) and so now you cannot rely on the result! Functional programming is all about avoiding such surprises. A programmer could give you `max1` and `max2` and both answers are correct. However, when they are used in reduce, in the particular way you're applying with `undefined`, you get a different result for each function. That kind of bug is the worst, because it's not clear where the problem is.

Comment: I already acknowledge that it works, but I'm explaining it's precarious and relies on JavaScript black magic, comparisons with `null` or `undefined`. If JavaScript were less permissive, it would read `undefined < ...` and throw an error, "cannot compare undefined with ...". The result cannot be _defined_ if the input is _undefined_.

Comment: Yes, javascript allows this, I do not find that it is really an abuse of use, otherwise you can also use  `const getMax=(arr=[])=>arr.reduce((a,c,i)=>(i&&a>c)?a:c,undefined)`

Answer (score 0):

Try use Math.max method:

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 1, 3, 4]
numbers.reduce((acc, rec) => Math.max(acc, rec))

//5
```

or

```
function max(numbers) {
  return list.reduce((acc, rec) => acc > rec ? acc : rec)
}
```

if you need find max value without Math.max.

Comment: simply do `Math.max(...numbers)`

Comment: Math.max working with numbers, but input is array of numbers, so I decided to combine this method with reduce.

Comment: yes, you have chosen to complicate things at minima